# if the value is different get color

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need your help, I have the code below that compares one column from different sheets, if some value is missing on the worksheet "B" Column A (Old update) the value will be highlighted on the Worksheet "A" Column A (Values updated)

Now:

- The column A from worksheet "A" and worksheet "B" have the same values (fixed) and i want to compare the values (this values are coming from a vlookup from worksheet "C") from Column F  worksheet "A" to the Column H of worksheet "B", and if there is different values the cell value should be highlighted on the Column F  worksheet "A".

(Worksheet "C" should not be part of the coding)

I am very lost coding that, please can you help me?
(i want to apply as private sub)

```
Sub missingvalue ()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim desWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, Val As String, dic As Object
Set srcWS = Sheets("B")
Set desWS = Sheets("A")
Dim LastRow As Long
arr1 = srcWS.Range("A2", srcWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
arr2 = desWS.Range("A2", desWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
    Val = arr1(i, 1)
    If Not dic.Exists(Val) Then
        dic.Add Key:=Val, Item:=i + 1
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(arr2, 1)
    Val = arr2(i, 1)
    If Not dic.Exists(Val) Then
        desWS.Range("A" & i + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(186, 208, 80)
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

I am not able to add imagine dont know why, i will try by words:

The current code works for the following example:

- Worksheet "A" Column A: (A1)-Alfred, (A2)-Charles (So the cell value with "Charles" is highlighted because is missing on Worksheet "B" Column A)
- Worksheet "B" Column A: (A1)-Alfred

What i want to do now is:

--Worksheet "A" Column A: (A1)-Alfred (A2)-Charles

--Worksheet "A" Column F: (F1)-Sweden (F2)- France (So the cell value with "France" on the column F is highlighted because is different on Worksheet "B" Column H for Column A with the cell value "Charles")

--Worksheet "B" Column A: (A1)-Alfred (A2)-Charles

--Worksheet "B" Column H: (H1)-Sweden (H2)-Spain

More schematic:

Worksheet A:

```
     A     |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F
1  Alfred  |       |       |       |       | Sweden
2  Charles |       |       |       |       | France
```

Worksheet B:

```
     A     |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F  |  G  |  H  
1  Alfred  |       |       |       |       |      |     | Sweden
2  Charles |       |       |       |       |      |     | Spain
```

I am lost how to re do the code to work on this way.

Comment: You've described what you want to achieve,  and the code you are using.  But not told us what your problem is: does the code error (if so on what line, for what values), does it produce the wrong results (if so, what result to you expect and what do you get).  Some sample data would help (as text so we can copy paste.  You can add an image as well to show the colours)

Answer (score 0):

Don't really need to use dictionary.  A couple more variables will help you with it

```
Sub missingvalue()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim desWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim strfind As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, lngRow As Long, lngDest As Long
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet B")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet A")
    
    LastRow = srcWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For lngRow = 2 To LastRow
        strfind = srcWS.Cells(lngRow, 1)
        If Not desWS.Columns(1).Find(what:=strfind, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            lngDest = desWS.Columns(1).Find(what:=strfind, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        End If
        If desWS.Cells(lngDest, 6).Value <> srcWS.Cells(lngRow, 8).Value Then
            desWS.Cells(lngDest, 6).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next lngRow
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: -James i tried your code and unfortunately is not working :(

Comment: Define 'not working'. Does it cause an error, or does it not give the results you are looking for?  If it's not producing the results you are looking for, please describe how they are different.

Comment: The Values on the column 6 from the Worksheet A are not highlighted. 
I want to run the code in Private Sub (under worksheet "A"), to be automatically when the difference between values  is seen

Answer (score 0):

A general rule in programming: never re-invent the wheel.

What you are describing, is the highlighting (or modification of colour) of a cell, based on the value (or lack there of) of another cell. Exactly for that reason, [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) has been invented.

You can base conditional formatting on a formula (in case the result is `TRUE` the formatting is applied). The combination of a `VLookup()` or a `Match()` function, possibly combined with a `If()` or `IfError()` should solve your problem.

**Edit**

After some trying (I've used the values you entered in the edited version of your question), I've written this formula (for checking the colour of Worksheet A, cell F1):

```
=VLookup(A1;B!$A$1:$H$2;8;0)=F1
```

This formula does the following:

- Take value A1 ("Alfred") and look for it in the table $A$1:$H$2 on worksheet B
- Once found this value, take the value of the eigth column (column "H", where you have the country references)
- Check if that found value corresponds with the country reference on worksheet A (column "F", value "F1" in this case)

(Remark: be careful with relative references (A1, F1) and absolute references ($A$1, $H$2))

This formula yields `TRUE` if the values correspond, and `FALSE` in case not (or not found). This can be used as a basis for conditional formatting. In case you have problems with this, I'd advise you to add "conditional-formatting" as a tag to your question, in order to have specialists on that matter seeing your question.

Comment: You have the example that i am working on on the post under the coding.

-Dominique the values on the column F they are coming from an worksheet "C" the formula is Iferror vlookup ( i am not sure how to use the formula you mention)

Comment: Dominique, 
Firstly thank you to create the structure.
I am trying the formula in conditional formatting and still is not working. :(
I tagged Conditional formatting on my post.

My values on the worksheet A starts on the row 6 but i thing is not relevant for that formula.